# How to open Excel in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I followed this site to get me started on my program, [here](http://vb.net-informations.com/excel-2007/vb.net_excel_2007_create_file.htm)

When I add the reference and declare my variables:

```
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Class XCel
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
End Class
```

I get an ambiguity error, " 'Application' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel' "

I've read a few pages saying to remove the reference then re-add it and updating the PIAs but none have helped.

Is there a simpler way to open an Excel? Something I'm missing in my code/project to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a simpler way to open an Excel?

The EPPlus open source project makes it much easier to work with Excel files than using Office Interop:

> EPPlus is a .net library that reads and writes Excel 2007/2010 files using the Open Office Xml format (xlsx).

http://epplus.codeplex.com/

> I get an ambiguity error, " 'Application' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel' "

I ran into the same error that you are getting now when I had PIA's for more than one Office version installed on the same machine.  I ended up resolving it by only installing the newest version of Excel on my development machine (because after all, I wanted to have the newest version of Office for general work) and creating a Virtual Machine that had the oldest version of Office that I needed to support that I used as a build machine to do the final release build and create the setup program for customers.

Comment: Thanks. I now need to figure out how to use EPPlus.

Comment: True, but it's easier to figure out EPPlus than Office Interop imho :-)

Comment: I spent most of the day trying different segments of code for Office.Interop. If I can spend the same time, or less, with EPPlus I'll call that a success. :p

Comment: i tried this Epplus... but when I want to add some image, it gives me error writing xml format of the xlsx. Sigh